# show custom data in Wordpress posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display some custom data in my category posts loop. I mean I want to create special div on my post template and I want to show data from this div in this posts loop. Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=7'); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class = "item">
    <div class="item_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(10); ?></div>
        <!-- here I want to display data from each post -->
        <div class = "my_custom_data">custom data</div>
        <a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "item_link">Show more...</a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;               
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Have you added the custom fields with info? How did you do this? You can do this as recommended here https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields or to make your own custom fields

Comment: @omukiguy I created the custom field with ACF plugin and added data. Now I want to display this data not only on the single.php template and in the page-blog.php (for example) loop where I display a thumbnail, title etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF has two powerful functions get_field() and the_field(). To retrieve a field value as a variable, use the get_field() function. This is the most versatile function which will always return a value for any type of field.

To display a field, use the the_field() in a similar fashion.

Now you need to get the name of the field e.g if it is 'custom_title'

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=7'); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class = "item">
    <div class="item_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class = "item_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(10); ?></div>
        <!-- here I want to display data from each post -->
        <div class = "my_custom_data"><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></div>
        <a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "item_link">Show more...</a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;               
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: So how should I connect <div class = "my_custom_data"><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></div> with my posts template (single.php for example). I mean I want to enter 'custom_title' in the post and display it in the post and in this loop both.

Comment: single.php also has a while loop

`
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <div class = "my_custom_data"><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></div>

<php

   the_post_navigation();

   // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
   if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
    comments_template();
   endif;

  endwhile; // End of the loop.
  ?>`

Comment: Just add the `<div class = "my_custom_data"><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></div>` to any loop for your post queries. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you very much.
Unfortunately, I can't vote for your answer because of my low reputation

Comment: That's great. No worries